# draw#rect core graphics, on top of a layer?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

Say you have this in a UIView,

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    c?.setLineWidth(10.0)
    c?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 10.0))
    c?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: 40.0))
    ... lots of complicated drawing here, sundry paths, colors, widths etc ...
    c?.strokePath()
}
```

Of course, it will draw the hell out of your drawing for you.

But say in the same UIView you do this ...

```
func setup() { // in inits, layout
    if nil etc {
      thingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
      self.layer.insertSublayer(thingLayer, at: 0)
      thingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor }
    thingLayer.frame = bounds
    let path = ... some fancy path
    thingLayer.path = path.cgPath
}
```

Indeed, the new yellow layer is drawn ***over*** the drawing in draw#rect.

How do you draw - using core graphics commands - either on to thingLayer, or perhaps on to another layer on top of all??

Core graphics commands:

```
    let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    c?.setLineWidth(10.0)
    c?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 10.0))
    c?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: 40.0))
    c?.strokePath()
```

seem to draw to a place directly above or on the main `.layer`

(Well that appears to be the case, as far as I can see.)

How do you draw - using core graphics commands - either on to thingLayer, or perhaps on to another layer on top of all??

Surely in draw#rect you can specify which cgLayer to draw to?

In draw#rect, can you make another cgLayer and draw to context, that cgLayer?

Comment: By the way, if you do anything based upon the `bounds`, you’ll want to move that to `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you noticed, I add bounties to every QA.  "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."   Also it often brings more interest and other worthwhile ideas, answers or comments, I've found.  thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bottom line, the [`draw(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw) is for rendering the root view of a `UIView` subclass. If you add sublayers, they will be rendered on top of whatever is done in the root view’s `draw(_:)`.

If you have a few paths currently performed in the `draw(_:)` that you want to render on top of the sublayer that you’ve added, you have a few options:

1. Move the paths to be stroked in their own `CAShapeLayer` instances and add them above the other sublayer that you’ve already added.
2. Consider the main `UIView` subclass as a container/content view, and add your own private `UIView` subviews (potentially with the “complicated” `draw(_:)` methods). You don’t have to expose these private subviews if you don’t want to.
3. Move the complicated drawing to the [`draw(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410757-draw) of a `CALayer` subclass and, again, add this sublayer above the existing sublayer that you’ve already created.
4. Given that the `thingLayer` is, effectively, only setting the background color, you could just set the background color of the view and not use a layer for this background color at all.

Comment: "is for rendering the root view of a UIView subclass" - ahhhhhhh.  (So, the root cgLayer, correct?  Which is on the root .layer )

Comment: in a sense @Rob item 3 is "the answer to the question".  If you really want to use draw#rect direct commands, on another layer, it seems you have to subclass a layer and use draw#in.  User Alexander mentioned this in a comment also.

Comment: @Fattie Why yes, I did say that. And somehow, our comments and stuff have been deleted. What's up with that?

Answer (score 1):

The `CALayer` hierarchy is a tree, where a root layer is first (e.g. the layer that comprises the background of a window), followed by its `sublayers` (an array of `CALayer` objects, stored and drawn in in back-to-front order), followed by their sublayers, and so on, recursively.

Your implementation of `UIView.draw(_ rect: CGRect)` is defining how the main layer of your view (`self.layer`) is drawn.

By adding your `CAShapeLayer` as a sublayer of `self.layer`, you're making it be draw *after* `self.layer`, which has the effect of it being drawn *above* `self.layer`, which contains the line you drew in `UIView.draw(_ rect: CGRect)`.

To resolve this, you need to put your stroke in sublayer *after* your `thingLayer`.

```
self.layer.insertSublayer(thingLayer, at: 0)
self.layer.insertSublayer(lineLayer, above: thingLayer)
```

By the way, you forgot to delegate to `super.draw(rect)`. It's not necessary for direct subclasses of `UIView` (since the base implementation doesn't do anything), but it is necessary for every other case, and it's generally a good habit to get into (lest you run into really obscure/frustrating drawing bugs).

Answer (score 0):

If your yellow shape layer doesn't change or move around independently, you could get rid of the CAShapeLayer and just draw the shape yourself at the top of your implementation of `draw(_:)`:

```
let path = // your fancy UIBezierPath
UIColor.yellow.setFill()
path.fill()
```

Otherwise, as other commenters have said, you'll need to move your drawing code into additional custom subclasses of UIView or CALayer, and stack them in the order you want.

Comment: Robin, true enough: But in general it's good to separate stuff out in computing.  Just one example is, we might be animating some of the layers in question one way or another; it's really sensible/easier in that case to have various layers.